# Kolmogorov Three series for independent exponential distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to use the Kolmogorov 3-series theorem for this problem:

Find the necessary and sufficient conditions for $\sum_{j=1}^nX_j$ to converge a.s when $(X_n)$ are independent and exponentially distributed.

So far I've tried:

For the first condition: 
$$
\sum_{n}P(|X_n|>c)=\sum_n \exp\left\{-c\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k\right\}
$$
which I don't know when this series could converge

The next two ones:

$$
\sum_{n} var(X_n1_{|x_n|<c})\leq\sum_{n}var(X_n)=\sum_{n}\frac{1}{\lambda_n^2} 
$$
and 
$$
\sum_n E(X_n1_{|X_n|<c})\leq\sum_nE(X_n)=\sum_{n}\frac{1}{\lambda_n}
$$
I don't know if my computation is good enough. I think I could say that if $\sum_n \frac{1}{\lambda_n}<\infty$, it should be enough for holding that $\sum_j X_j$ a.s.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't believe the Kolmogorov three-series theorem is needed here. It can be proven that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\lambda_n}<\infty$.